# Java LaTeX components in JFrame

Tags: java, latex, formula

Is it possible to show LaTeX Formulas like
[image]
in a JFrame? And if yes, is there a good documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

[JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/) , [SnuggleTeX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/) and [jLaTeXMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/) . Interesting link to a similar discussion from another site on stackexchange - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41609/tex-rendering-in-a-java-application